# Reference the table generated by Shapes.AddTable method (PowerPoint)

Tags: vba, powerpoint

The method Shapes.AddTable method (PowerPoint) returns a Shapes object. However, when in Macro I have

```
Dim pptTable As Table
pptTable = pptSlide.Shapes.AddTable(2, 1)
```

It face "Run-time error '91' / "object variable or With block variable not set error".

I tried different ways. I need to set in a loop the cells of the table with new text.

```
pptTable.Cell(1, Count Mod 2).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = DataLine
```

Any ideas on how I can achieve this, please?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: SET  pptTable = pptSlide.Shapes.AddTable(2, 1)   ?

Comment: Also, you'll need to declare pptTable as a Shape object --> `Dim pptTable As Shape`.

Comment: Please check this previous answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65061989/vb-powerpoint-macro-create-a-table-and-reference-it